# Calling OnDeltapos() from OnPointerdown() in MFC

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, spinner

I have a `CSpinButtonCtrl` class subclassed called `MySpinButtonCtrl`. In this class I have an `OnDeltapos` event declared which is in charge of increment and decrement numeric values on my spinner:

```
 void CMySpinButtonCtrl::OnDeltapos(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) 
{
     NM_UPDOWN* pNMUpDown = (NM_UPDOWN*)pNMHDR;

    if (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) < 0)    // ctrl key pressed ==> limit value
    {
        int lower, upper;
        GetRange(lower, upper);

        if (pNMUpDown->iDelta < 0)
            *pResult = MySetSpinPos(lower);     // lower limit
        else
            *pResult = MySetSpinPos(upper);     // upper limit
    }
    else
    {
        int nDelta;
        if (GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) < 0)  // shift key pressed==> speed x 10
            nDelta = 10 * pNMUpDown->iDelta;
        else
            nDelta = pNMUpDown->iDelta;

        *pResult = MySetSpinPos(pNMUpDown->iPos + nDelta);
    }
}
```

When I keep pressed my spinner with the **left mouse button** it works perfectly fine, however when I try pressing my spinner with a **touch screen**, it needs **two** pressed gestures.

I have tried catching the press touch event with `OnPointerDown`, but I have no idea how to implement it:

```
afx_msg LRESULT CMySpinButtonCtrl::OnPointerdown(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (IS_POINTER_PRIMARY_WPARAM(wParam))
    {
        //TODO
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to call `OndeltaPos` from `OnPointerDown`?

I will appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Use a timer. Whenever the timer fires, call `OnDeltaPos` manually (you'll need to fake up the `NM_UPDOWN` structure yourself. When the button is released, cancel the timer.

Comment: A long touch press is converted to a right-click event by the system. You can try to disable the long press gesture on the spinner control. I wasn't able to find the document on MSDN I was looking for. However, [Touch Input Support in Windows Vista](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms699430.aspx) may be applicable as well. Also keep in mind, that touch input changed a lot between Vista, Windows 7, and Windows 8. You may need different approaches for different target versions.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I have encounter a problem, when I fake NM_UPDOWN structure I need to know previously the **iDelta** property of  NM_UPDOWN, are there any way to know it when user touch up or down button of the spinner?

Comment: When you get a real message (from the touch down event) save the delta property somewhere - e.g. in a window property using `SetProp`.