# Detecting Up / Down arrows in CSpinButtonCtrl MFC C++

Tags: mfc, spinner

Is there any way to differentiate when the Up or Down arrow of a `CSpinButtonCtrl` is pressed?

I am trying to use the `OnPointerdown` event, but I don't know how to do it...

```
afx_msg LRESULT CMySpinButtonCtrl::OnPointerdown(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   if(IS_POINTER_PRIMARY_WPARAM(wParam))
   {
       //TODO
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I will appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: One way would be to check the cursor position. If it's in the top half of the control it's on the up button.

Comment: The correct way would be to handle the `UDN_DELTAPOS` notification code via `ON_NOTIFY(UDN_DELTAPOS, ...)`. You'd receive a `NMUPDOWN` structure, where the `iDelta` member is a signed integer that contains the proposed change in position (a positive value indicates up, a negative value down).

Comment: Your question seems related to your other one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49750680/calling-ondeltapos-from-onpointerdown-in-mfc

Answer (score 14):

> Is there any way to differentiate when the Up or Down arrow of a [`CSpinButtonCtrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/mfc/reference/cspinbuttonctrl-class) is pressed?

You should use [`UDN_DELTAPOS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759903(v=vs.85).aspx) to do this.

- **Right-click** the control in the **Resource Editor** and select **Add Event Handler**:

[image: Add Event Handler]

- Select the `UDN_DELTAPOS` message and click **Add and Edit**:

[image: UDN_DELTAPOS]

- You will be provided with skeleton code:

  ```
  void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnDeltaposSpin1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
  {
      LPNMUPDOWN pNMUpDown = reinterpret_cast<LPNMUPDOWN>(pNMHDR);
      // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
      *pResult = 0;
  }
  ```
- The [`NMUPDOWN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759893(v=vs.85).aspx) article explains about the structure that you use. What you need to do is test the `iDelta` value. Example:

  ```
  void CColumnOrderDlg::OnDeltaposSpinColumns(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) 
  {
      LPNMUPDOWN pNMUpDown = reinterpret_cast<LPNMUPDOWN>(pNMHDR);

      if (pNMUpDown != nullptr)
      {
          if( pNMUpDown->iDelta > 0)
              // Up - Do stuff;
          else if(pNMUpDown->iDelta < 0)
              // Down - Do stuff;
      }

      *pResult = 0;
  }
  ```

---

There is also a useful article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/mfc/using-cspinbuttonctrl) where it states:

> If you use a spin control for some other purpose, for example, to page through a sequence of windows or dialog boxes, then add a handler for the `UDN_DELTAPOS` message and perform your custom action there.